# Optimising the iteration $g(x)= \frac{1}{1+\beta} |\beta x - e^{x} |$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

I want to find a solution of $x + ln(x) = 0$ and I know the solution is somewhere in the interval $[0.5,0.6]$.

I found a good iteration of the solution to be $g(x)= \frac{1}{1+\beta} |\beta x - e^{x} |$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Now I want to choose an optimal beta i.e. a beta for which the absolute value of the derivative is minimal for values $x\in [0.5,0.6]$.

I have $$|g'(x)| =  \left\lvert\frac{\beta - e^{x}}{1+\beta} \right\rvert $$

Would it be correct to treat $$f(\beta):= |g'(x)|$$ now as a function of beta and finding the minimum? The problem is, if I do that, I find that the roots of $f'(\beta)$ are actually complex! I want $\beta$ to be real. Furthermore, I haven't taken in account that $x\in [0.5,0.6]$, which might be relevant. **How do I find the optimal beta?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to see that the function $g’(x)$ is monotonic, so the maximum of $|g’(x)|$ at any interval $$ is attained at its endpoints. Thus we have to minimize

$$\max\left\{\left\lvert\frac{\beta - e^{0.5}}{1+\beta} \right\rvert, \left\lvert\frac{\beta - e^{0.6}}{1+\beta} \right\rvert\right\}=\max\left\{\left\lvert 1-\frac{a}{1+\beta} \right\rvert, \left\lvert 1-\frac{b}{1+\beta} \right\rvert\right\},$$

where $a=e^{0.5}+1$ and $b=e^{0.6}+1$. But $$\frac{\frac{a}{1+\beta}}{\frac{b}{1+\beta}}=\frac ab$$ is a positive constant. Therefore if $1+\beta$ is negative then the minimum of the maximums is at least $1$, and if $1+\beta$ is positive then the minimum of the maximums is less than $1$ and it is attained when $$\frac{b}{1+\beta}-1=1-\frac{a}{1+\beta},$$ that is when $$\beta=\frac{a+b}2-1=\frac{e^{0.5}+ e^{0.6}}2.$$